# On which side of object should friction force be drawn on a vector diagram?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction, vectors

Let's say a box is moving to the right and friction is slowing it down. The friction force vector pointing to the left and the object moving to the right, should the vector be drawn on the left side of the object like this:

: [image]

Or on the right side of the object like this:

[image]

Comment: Represent the box as a dot.  Problem solved.

Comment: I would put it along the bottom of the box.  It is a distributed force, not a point force

Answer (score 1):

Surely it does not matter.... The actual force is distributed along the bottom of the block, but the two ways of drawing are *equipollent*.

Two force systems are equipollent  if they have the same total force and total moment about  any  arbitrary point.

Answer (score 0):

Force is a vector quantity. Parallel shifting of vectors is allowed while judging translational motion. You can pretty much put that arrow anywhere on the block so long as you know it is actually applied throughout the area of the part of the block in contact with incline.